Facebook Login returning 'undefined' with capacitor-commuty/facebook-login
My current env is:
    "@ionic/angular": "^8.0.0-rc.2",  
    "@capacitor/app": "^6.0.0",  
    "@capacitor/core": "^6.0.0",  
    "@capacitor/ios": "^6.0.0",  
    "@capacitor-community/facebook-login": "^6.0.0",  
    ...

I have the app set up per the very simple instructions found here: https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login?tab=readme-ov-file#ios-configuration. Yet when I run login(), the response is 'undefined'
FacebookLogin.login({ permissions: [] }).then((response) => {
      console.log('RESPONSE', JSON.stringify(response)); // logs undefined
      let token = '';

      if (response.accessToken) {
        token = response.accessToken.token;
      }

      return FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
    });

Research:
I looked at the source code for the javascript for the @capacitor-community/facebook-login plugin, and see that it should never return undefined as it will even reject the promise with a response object pre this line: https://github.com/capacitor-community/facebook-login/blob/master/src/web.ts#L101
I confirmed that the app ID from FB matches what's in Firebase and the info.plist file.
I confirmed the client token in the info.plist file matches FB. (not the APP Secret)
I'm aware of a recent change to the Facebook Login SDK but suspect this is part of the native code
Similar issue (I think, the screenshots are not in English) with no response in the ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/facebook-capacitor-plugin-v-6-0-0-changes-to-ios-sdk-anyone-knows-about-it/241373
If I log in again, I get something but I suspect it's a refresh token because Firebase then errors out with:
{"code": "auth/invalid-credential", "customData": {"appName": "[DEFAULT]"}, "name": "FirebaseError"}

thoughts?

I was able to login with the demo/angular app in the plugin repo. The demo doesn't use firebase and that is where the error is occurring. I'm looking for any documentation that explains what Firebase is looking for here

In case anyone comes across this:
The first issue had to deal with Safari having a long delay in populating the results of the sign-in response in the console. The result wasn't undefined after all.
The Firebase error is because of a poorly documented scenario where you must use the result.credential.accessToken from the result not the result.accessToken.token
